# Is it possible to get the type of a variable while computing completion suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm thinking of creating a VSCode extension to help people use a library I am creating. I've looked in 50 places and can only see documentation on getting the plain text of the document in which the completion suggestions are triggered.

My library exposes a function with two parameters, both objects with the same keys, but the first one will be defined already and the 2nd one will be passed in as an object literal. For example

```ts
const obj1 = {a:1, b:2};
doLibraryThing(obj1, {a:[], b:[]});
```

I want to provide code completion, or a snippet, or anything that can detect that `doLibraryThing` is being called, and know what properties were defined in `obj1`, even though usually it will be imported from another file; and then use those properties to generate the suggestion with the same properties, `{a:[], b:[]}`.

Is this possible?